# Identifying a ship in Sydney Harbour

Tags: 20th-century, australia, nautical

I am trying to identify the ship in this picture in order to date the photograph.
The writing on the back says it is "Aquatania" (sic) but when I search for that name on the internet the Aquitania has four funnels and this one only has two.
[image]

Comment: The ship's name is actually Aqu\*i\*tania. I corrected it and added a "sic" after your transcription of the name from the back of the photo, on the assumption that you copied it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Having a date for that picture might be helpful, but my best guess is that is a picture of the [RMS Mauretania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Mauretania_%281938%29), taken in the spring of 1940 while she was in Sydney harbor (along with the 3-funnel Queen Mary) to pick up troops for deployment to the Middle East. The paint scheme is fairly distinctive, as the all-gray was a wartime paint job. During peacetime she had a black and white paint job to help her stand out, whereas you can only see one tone of color in this photo.

Here's a photo of her underway with the wartime paint job.
[image]

[Here's a website](http://www.nfsa.gov.au/blog/2011/03/02/home-movie-footage-rms-queen-mary/) that goes into a nice bit of detail about her trip to Sydney harbor along with the Queen Mary (a 3-funnel ship). Incredibly, there's even [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xB7aUYIwo0w#t=182) showing both of them during their wartime duty, some of it shot in Sydney I believe.

Another possibility is the Queen Elizabeth, which looked very much like the Mauretania on the outside, and was also used as a troopship during the war.

Comment: There's a nice shot in the video starting at about [8:01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xB7aUYIwo0w#t=8m1s) that looks to me like the same ship underway near the same bridge.